# Can you help me with col-md troubles?

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap

I have some problems with my dashboard. I want to combine some files, without my table "Cursos" to move down and lose its place. What I want is that the table stays fixed when I scroll the table of "Recursos y actividades". I am posting it as I have coded my dashboard.

This is the code:

```
<div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <div class="panel panel-default">
                        <div class="panel-heading">
                                    <div class="icon"><i class="icon20 i-users-5"></i></div>
                                    <h4>Usuarios</h4>
                                    <a href="#" class="minimize"></a>
                        </div> <!-- End .panel-heading -->
                                <div class="panel-body">    
                                    <ul id="myTab" class="nav nav-tabs">
                                        <li><a href="#tabla" data-toggle="tab">Lista de usuarios</a></li>   
                                        <li><a href="#usuarios" data-toggle="tab">Gráfica</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#managers" data-toggle="tab">Managers</a></li>
                                    </ul>
                                    <div class="tab-content">
                                        <div class="tab-pane fade in active" id="tabla">
                                            <div class="panel-body">
                                                 <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover" id="dataTable">
                                                    <?php require_once ("mod/dashboard/dashboard-usuarios.php");?>
                                                 </table>
                                                 <?
                                                echo $CFG->mdl_user;
                                                $idresult = mysql_query ("SELECT count(*) from mdl_user");
                                                    if ($idresult==0){
                                                        echo "Sentencia incorrecta llamado a tabla: mdl_user";
                                                    } 
                                                    else{
                                                        $nregistrostotal = mysql_result ($idresult);
                                                        echo "Hay $nregistrostotal usuarios en la plataforma";
                                                        mysql_free_result($idresult);
                                                    }
                                                ?>
                                                <div class="form-group">
                                                    <label class="col-lg-2 control-label" for="animated">Limite de Usuarios</label>
                                                    <div class="col-lg-10">
                                                        <div class="progress progress-striped active tip" title="90%">
                                                            <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" style="width: 90%;"></div>
                                                        </div>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div><!-- End .control-group  -->
                                            </div> <!--termina panel-body-->
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="tab-pane fade" id="usuarios">
                                            <div class="panel-body">
                                                <div class="chart-donut" id="usuarios"style="width: 106%; height:240px; padding: 10px; position: relative;"></div>
                                                <br>

                                            </div><!-- End .panel-body -->
                                        </div>

                                        <div class="tab-pane fade" id="managers">
                                            <div class="panel-body">
                                                <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover" id="dataTable">
                                                    <tbody>
                                                        <tr class="gradeA">
                                                            <td>Luis A.</td>
                                                        </tr>
                                                        <tr class="gradeA">
                                                            <td>Ana B.</td>
                                                        </tr>
                                                    </tbody>
                                                </table>
                                            </div><!--termina panel-body-->
                                        </div>
                                    </div>                                                          
                                </div> <!-- Termina el panel-body -->                                                   
                    </div>  <!-- Termina el panel-default -->
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <div class="panel panel-default">
                        <div class="panel-heading">
                            <div class="icon"><i class="icon16 i-stats"></i></div> 
                            <h4>Registros</h4>
                            <a href="#" class="minimize"></a>
                        </div><!-- End .panel-heading -->
                            <div class="panel-body">
                                    <ul id="myTab" class="nav nav-tabs">
                                        <li><a href="#hora" data-toggle="tab">Hora</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#semana" data-toggle="tab">Semana</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#mes" data-toggle="tab">Mes</a> </li>
                                    </ul>
                                <div class="tab-content">
                                    <div class="tab-pane fade in active" id="hora">
                                        <div class="panel-body">
                                            <div class="chart-bars-ordered" style="width: 100%; height: 150px; margin-top: 3px; padding: 0px; position: relative;"></div>
                                        </div><!-- End .panel-body -->
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="tab-pane fade_1" id="semana">
                                        <div class="panel-body">
                                            <div class="chart-bars-stacked" style="width: 100%; height: 150px; margin-top: 3px; padding: 0px; position: relative;"></div>
                                        </div><!-- End .panel-body -->
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="tab-pane fade_2" id="mes">
                                        <div class="panel-body">
                                            <div class="chart-bars-horizontal" style="width: 100%; height: 150px; margin-top: 3px; padding: 0px; position: relative;"></div>
                                        </div><!-- End .panel-body -->
                                    </div>
                                </div> 
                            </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <div class="panel panel-default">
                        <div class="panel-heading">
                            <div class="icon"><i class="icon20  i-drawer-3"></i></div>
                            <h4>Recursos y actividades</h4>
                            <a href="#" class="minimize"></a>
                        </div><!-- End .panel-heading -->
                        <div class="panel-body center">
                            <?php 
                                require_once("mod/dashboard/dashboard-actividades.php");
                            ?>
                        </div><!-- End .panel-body center--> 
                        <br>                                    
                        <br>
                    </div><!-- End .widget -->
                </div>
            </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-5">
                            <div class="panel panel-default">
                                <div class="panel-heading">
                                    <div class="icon"><i class="icon20  i-drawer-3"></i></div>
                                    <h4>Cursos</h4>
                                    <a href="#" class="minimize"></a>
                                </div><!-- End .panel-heading -->
                                <?require_once("mod/dashboard/dashboard-cursos.php");?>
                            </div>                          
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use    { position:fixed } as css for the required table. This would position the table relative to the browser window. Add other appropriate styles to make it look the way you would like as you scroll down the page. For more information mess with the css code in http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/playit.asp?filename=playcss_position&preval=fixed